# How to disable download warning [Safe Browsing] in Chrome 62 via WebDriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Could you help me with disabling downloading warning or `Safe Browsing` in **Chrome 62** via **WebDriver**?

Thank you in advance!

> P.S.: --safebrowsing-disable-download-protection hasn't helped me since Chrome 61
>
> P.S.: Maybe there is exist any workaround how to whitelist XML files...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem recreating the user profile.

Comment: Could you please clarify this moment? Cuz, when the browser is opened by a web drive it creates a new instance with a new user profile. Did you do anything specific?